# BottomNavigationView setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener is deprecated in Material Component version 1.4.0. What to use now?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android

BottomNavigationView `setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener` is deprecated with Material Component version 1.4.0.

What to use now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [the deprecation message](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/720088c5c2462dbaaa90490bca04bb3bbdc708b1/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView.java#L234):

> Use `NavigationBarView#setOnItemReselectedListener(OnItemReselectedListener)` instead.

So just replace `setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener` with `setOnItemReselectedListener` and change your listener to a `NavigationBarView.OnItemReselectedListener`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation, it seems like you can call the listener interface directly and it will set the listeners internally since it's supported by both bottom navigation and navigation rail now.

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/95a769c373792d2fce70d7ee21f3857f65e9d74e/docs/components/NavigationRail.md

```
NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when(item.itemId) {
        R.id.item1 -> {
            // Respond to navigation item 1 click
            true
        }
        R.id.item2 -> {
            // Respond to navigation item 2 click
            true
        }
        else -> false
    }
}
```