# Latest BottomNavigtionView

Tags: java, android, deprecated, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

I am creating an Android app and I stumbled upon the fact that the previous way to create a bottom navigation view has been deprecated.

This is the error I am getting:

```
'setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener)' is deprecated
```

I am searching everywhere for this, but there is no website that shows the latest & updated way to do this.

What is the latest way to create a proper BottomNavigtionView? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68248515/bottomnavigationview-setonnavigationitemreselectedlistener-is-deprecated-with-ma

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BottomNavigationView setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener is deprecated with Material compoment version 1.4.0. What to user now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68248515/bottomnavigationview-setonnavigationitemreselectedlistener-is-deprecated-with-ma)

Comment: Thanks a lot....that was the thing I was looking for. I wonder how I missed that page, I was surfing for almost 30 mins!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes `setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener` is deprected now. To perform click operation on Google Bottom navigation you have to use the `bottomNavigation.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)` and extend `NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener` in your actvity/fragment

`bottomNavigation.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)` and then override `onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem)`

Example `Kotlin`:

```
bottomNavigation.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    when(item.itemId){
        R.id.your_menu_id->{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        ///
    }
    return true
}
```

or

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener{
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.your_menu_id-> {
               Toast.makeText(this,"Click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
            }
           ///
        }
        false
    }
```

And for reselection use `bottomNav.setOnItemReselectedListener(this)` and extend `NavigationBarView.OnItemReselectedListener` and override  `onNavigationItemReselected(item: MenuItem)`